# MySQL 8 . "secure_file_priv" error. can't overwrite inorder to change the safe mode for loading data from .CSV file

Tags: mysql

I've looked in previously asked questions and couldn't find the answer.

I created a table and want to load the data from a .CSV file using the following code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\...\*.csv'
INTO TABLE table_a
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '/n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

but keep getting back this:
"Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement"

Any suggestions?

PS - once I overcome this, could you please explain how to load .CSV data from an online URL instead of downloading the file first?

Comment: What is the output for `SELECT @@secure_file_priv;`? PS. `'C:\...\*.csv'` is wrong - only one definite file loading supported. PPS. Do not forget to quote (double) backslashes in string literal - or use common slash symbols `/` instead of backslashes.

Comment: @Akina `SELECT @@secure_file_priv;` gives me the same output as `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` **PS.** I am using the full file location, just didn't want to write irrelevant extra details. **PPS** You mean at the file address I need to write "\" instead of \?

Comment: @Akina C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\

Comment: This means that the file which you try to load must posess in this directory strictly. `LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\myfile.csv' ...`

Comment: @Akina Thanks It worked! but at the end I didn't use it. instead I left-cliked on the database and used the "Table data import wizard" which worked great.
**BTW** How can I pull data from a webpage, i.e using a "WWW.../file-name.csv"?

Comment: Wizard loads and parses the file itself, then sends parsed data to MySQL row-by-row. *How can I pull data from a webpage* You must upload the file into `secure_file_priv` folder then load it. Or upload to some other place which is local for MySQL and use *LOAD DATA **LOCAL** INFILE* (which must be enabled separately).